# WCF TransportCredentialOnly not sending username and password

Tags: wcf

I have the following WCF client configuration:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="basicHttpOCCWS" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="100000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000" messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                    maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />            
      </security>
   </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

In code, I am setting the username and password as follows:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _cacledUserId;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _cachedPassword;
```

However, the web service running on Tomcat is returning an error:

"An authentication object was not found in the security context."

When I look at the HTTP header, it is missing credential information as shown below:

```
POST /occ600webservice/services/OCC_WS HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""
Host: 192.54.173.130:8080
Content-Length: 2223
Expect: 100-continue
```

Why are my credentials not being sent?

TIA.

Klaus

Comment: In order to properly format, you need to highlight code and xml sections, and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard. Makes huge difference!

Answer (score 23):

For others who run into the same problem, wrap each call to the secured web service resource like this:

```
var client = new WCClient(); 

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
   var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
   httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = 
     "Basic " + 
     Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" +
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] =
               httpRequestProperty;

   client.DoSomething();
}
```

see the following links:

- [Inserting headers 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2008/07/08/adding-headers-to-a-call-http-version.aspx)
- [Inserting headers 2](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2008/07/avoid-http-401-roundtrip-with-adding.html)

Comment: @e28Markaveli > I have tried this but when calling the service method(client.DoSomthing()) I will get the fallowing exception : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=\"localhost\. I really need to pass these client indenification completely without security.

Comment: This sounds like a service configuration issue.  Is your service configured for Basic authentication scheme?

Comment: i had the same problem. This is the only solution that helped me. If I could vote this up 100 times, I would.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You're just manually creating the HTTP header instead of WCF doing it for you, you don't even need ClientCredentials at this point.

Comment: Awesome this resolved my issue, but I still don't understand is this a configuration issue or a WCF bug ?

Comment: Using security mode TransportCredentialsOnly and transport clientCredentialType Basic, as is often suggested, doesn't seem to work to pre-emptively send this header over http.  (Maybe if the non-WCF web-service were to give a 401 unauthorised, it'd resend with credentials?)   I've tried other configuration options and am now giving up and going this manual route.  [Actually, just realised I was getting failures over httpS too (but couldn't intercept those headers) - maybe the WCF config just doesn't work preemptively?]

Comment: @mwardm is correct. With 'TransportCredentialOnly', WCF does not send the credentials preemptively. .NET 2.0 .asmx web services had a PreAuthenticate option, but that seems lost. The above hack seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the security element to also include the message element specifying the clientCredentialType to be UserName otherwise the transport doesn't know that you want to use the ClientCredentials.UserName object that you filled in.

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
</security>
```